How to scan below qr code in android/react native app?
Tried several libraries such as react native camera-kit, react native vision camera and google ML kit tried all format(QR,aztec,data matrix etc) but none of them scan it but found only 1 app on playstore which scans this.
click on demo qr to view qr code demo qr
expecting a solution on how to scan it and which type of qr is this.
